# What is the usage of the = operator here?

Tags: c++

Below is my solution for finding the number of trailing zeros in a factorial, it works, i'm posting it to give an idea of how the algorithm works which is the sum of quotients of n divided by 5 ^ i, where i>0.

```
#include <cmath>
long zeros(long n) {
    long sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1;; ++i) {
        int m = n / pow(5, i);
        if (m == 0)
            break;
        else sum += m;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

I saw this solution which confused me with its use of the `=` operator. What does `=5` mean in this context?

```
long zeros(long n) {
    long result = 0;
    while(n)
        result += n/=5;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: It's not the `=` operator that appears here. You seem to perfectly understand what `+=` means, but you missed the obvious explanation of what `/=` must therefore be doing.

Comment: Oh. My brain just immediately assumed it was something more advanced. I just dont use ```/=``` much.

Comment: Besides `+=` and `/=`, there's also `-=`, `*=`, `<<=`, `>>=`, and a bunch of others. You don't need to use every one of them, all the time, to understand their consistent purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `result += n/=5` is equivalent to first updating the value of `n` to `n/5` and then updating the value of `result` to `result + n` where `n` is now `n/5`.

```cpp
// result += n/=5 is same as doing
n = n / 5;
result = result + n;
```

Here the `/=` is analogous to `+=` in the sense that `n/=5` is equivalent to `n = n/5`

Comment: @ggorlen Thanks for pointing out. I have updated the answer to remove the ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

Its to assign a value or variable to a variable
i.e m = n means that if n is 15, m will be the value of  n which is 15